# SQL Server Manager not detecting local databases

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to generate script for my sql local database created using visual studio 2010. When i open sql server manager and connect to localhost or SQLEXPRESS the database created does not seem to appear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you generated your `.mdf` with Visual Studio - did you **attach** it to your SQL Server instance??

In VS, you can setup *stand-alone* `.mdf` files which are **not** automatically visible inside SQL Server Management Studio. Those are typically referenced by your application using a connection string that contains

```
AttachDbFileName=(path)\Mydatabase.mdf;User Instance=true
```

If you have such an `.mdf` database - you need to first attach it to your SQL Server instance before you see it in SQL Server Management Studio.